# Bound cell formula to a sorted table

Tags: excel

I have a table at `A1:C5` and also formula at `H50` `=C1+C2` and `H51` `=C3+C4+C5`

How can I sort the table by column `B` without messing up `H50` and `H51`? (I want that the formulas will be 'bound' to the cells even if the row position is changing)

Thanks.

Comment: Use INDEX perhaps.

Comment: Your table doesn't seem to have any headers. How are you sorting?

Comment: @teylyn, do you mean it should start from A2?

Comment: No, but you call it a "table". That typically means that the first row contains column headers. In an Excel table object these do magical things. But your formulas suggest that your data starts in row 1, hence no label row, hence my question. I'm not telling you it "should", I'm asking what is there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have a few cells in the formulas, you can assign each cell in range C1 to C5 individual range names, then use these names in the formulas in H50 and H51. By addressing the cells with their name, the result will not change when the named cell changes position.

Comment: Can you give example for how to assign each cell in range to individual range names?

Comment: Select a cell or cells, and in the field to the left of the formula bar, type in your choice of name for that selection. You can then refer to those cells by name in your formulas. It's either `F3` or `Ctrl F3` to open the name manager list to revise afterwards.

Comment: You can use any method you want to define range name. Use the Name Manager, or the name box. Whatever floats your boat. If you don't know how to create range names, do a Google search. There are lots of tutorials out there.